# openGL program fails to link with LDC

Tags: opengl, linker, d

I am trying to compile a simple program in D Language with ldc, but it
seems that it can not link with openGL.

clang works fine:

```
clang `pkg-config --cflags --libs glu gl libglfw` triangle.c
```

LDC info

```
LDC - the LLVM D compiler (trunk):
based on DMD v2.060 and LLVM 3.2svn
Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
```

and result of pkg-config

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs glu gl libglfw

-I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -lGLU -lGL -lglfw
```

CommandLine

```
$ ldc2 -L-lglfw -L-L/opt/X11/lib -L-lGL -L-lGLU -w triangle.d

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__D2gl10glVertex3fFfffZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl10glViewportFiiiiZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl12glClearColorFffffZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl12glMatrixModeFkZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl12glTranslatefFfffZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl14glLoadIdentityFZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl5glEndFZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl7glBeginFkZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl7glClearFkZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl9glColor3fFfffZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D2gl9glRotatefFffffZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D3glu14gluPerspectiveFddddZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
  "__D3glu9gluLookAtFdddddddddZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in triangle.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: /usr/bin/gcc failed with status: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you declaring the OpenGL functions? `__D2gl10glVertex3fFfffZv` is the symbol `gl.glVertex3f`, which is a D symbol in the module `gl`.

The OpenGL functions in the libs have C linkage, so you need to use `extern(C)` when declaring them, e.g.

```
extern(C) void glVertex3f(float, float, float);
```

If you have all the declarations in a file then you can also use the `{}` notation:

```
extern(C)
{
    void glVertex3f(float, float, float);
    ...
}
```

When trying to fix linker errors, it can sometimes help to look at the symbols you are linking with. You can use the `nm` utility with `grep` to find how the symbol is mangled:

```
% nm /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries/libGL.dylib | grep glVertex3f
0000000000003b13 T _glVertex3f
0000000000003b2e T _glVertex3fv
```

As you can see, the symbol is spelled `_glVertex3f`, not `__D2gl10glVertex3fFfffZv`, which is why it cannot be found. You can tell yours is a D symbol by the leading `__D` as well as all the extra mangling information (for example the `fff` at the end indicates the 3 `float` parameters). In general, the C symbols you find in most libraries are very simple, containing only a leading underscore following by the name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the problem that I added a Conditional Compilation version (OSX) {extern (C):} but it doesn't work...